# Why can the common name of a key-pair be empty?

Tags: tls, certificates

I just realized that, using openssl req - new -key foo.key -out newcert.csr, you can actually have an empty CN value.

What's the value of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is just 'informative' and only have a meaning in case of session based exchanges.

A key-pair in a certificate can be used to encrypt data without a session.

Example:

You encrypt a file with your private key and give your public key to some peoples. The CN has a low value to identify the source, the public key itself is enough to decrypt the file if you're sure the file come from trusted source.

This allow file transfer on clear-text protocols with a end point encryption/decryption. The CN has a low value in this case as the key have to match.

Comment: In particular, CommonName _or_ SAN (see Yorick's answer) **equal to (routed) hostname** is needed for _some_ SSL/TLS **servers**, especially HTTPS. It is not needed for clients, which do not need to have a hostname or at least domainname at all. It is not needed though sometimes useful for S/MIME. It is not needed and often not meaningful for codesigning. It is not needed for intermediate CA (although using openssl commandline for intermediate CA may be unwise). There are many uses of PKI where it isn't needed and openssl doesn't exclude them.

Comment: @dave you should turn this comment in an answer ;)

Comment: A key-pair is not 'in a certificate'. The certificate wraps the public key only. 'Give your public key to some people' is a contradiction in terms. *Anybody* can acquire the public key. That is its whole purpose. The technique you describe is nonsense.

Comment: @ejp well SSL is not the only use of certificates. If anyone can acquire the public key, prove it by creating a cyphered file so I am the only one able to read it with my personal private key...

Comment: @ejp the other way around, if I send you by mistake a file cyphered with my private key, you won't be able to read it if I don't provide you my public key... That's the whole idea behind this post.

Answer (score 1):

From the [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.6):

> The subject name MAY be carried in the subject field and/or the
> subjectAltName extension.

Its not mandatory. In fact you do not always need a common name field. If you build a private chain of trust, say for a preshared key certificate, you have on use for this field.